# How to convert this sentence into a first order logic well formed formula?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic, nlp, first-order-logic

I am trying to convert the following sentence to a well formed formula using first-order logic(Predicate logic).

> All towers are of the same color.

I have defined the following predicates:

> Tower(x) :: x is a tower.
>
> Color(x, y) :: x is of color y

I am not able to convert the aforementioned sentence into a well formed formula using the above predicates. Is it possible to convert it using the above predicates or some new predicate should be required. Please advise.

EDIT: Forgot to add a detail. There are only three available colours in the world (red, green, blue). Can this detail be used. Does that make any difference to the solution?

Comment: Where's the **homework** tag?

Comment: Didn't know such a tag existed. Anyways updated the tags now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a Y1 such that for all X Tower(X) implies Color(X, Y1)

Comment: I had thought of this, but can you please explain how does it put the constraint that the color of all such towers should be same. As you have used the existential quantifier to quantify variable Y1, which says that there is "atleast" one Y1. Not "at most", which is how I thought the sentence's meaning should be pronounced.

Comment: @stressed I would say that your "at most" part is covered by David's answer, because if you consider Y1 and Y2 satisfying his property, then taking some X such that Tower(X), we have Color(X,Y1) and Color(X,Y2). Assuming a tower can only have one color, you get Y1=Y2. Of course we assume here that there exists a tower.

Comment: @Dunaril Please correct me if I am wrong. Let us say there are 2 towers x1, x2 in our world. Now using David's formula, we can have Color(x1,y1) and Color(x2, y2). But we do not want that, we want to put a constraint such that colors of both x1, y1 are same.

Comment: @Dunaril: no need to assume the existence of a tower. Even the existence of a color need not be assumed, if the formula is prefixed with "If there exist X and Y such that Tower(X) and Color(X,Y), then..."

Comment: @stressed_geek: the constraint is David's formula, since from that and Color(x1,y1) and Color(x2,y2), it follows that y1 = y2. They are different variables denoting the same entity (a single color).

Comment: @stressed It depends on whether a same tower can have different colors, that is, if you can have both Color(x1,y1) and Color(x1,y2). If this is the case, then you cannot have your "at most" indeed. But if there is only one color possible for one tower, then your y1 and y2 are equal because if they are both satisfying David's rule then we have Color(x1,y1) and Color(x1,y2).

Answer (score 2):

Let's not assume that any towers or colors exist.

```
tower(x) ∧ tower(y) ∧ color(x,z) → color(y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting this on StackOverflow, I realized that the problem is more suitable for [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/). So I had reposted the problem there.

Although, Dave's solution is perfectly correct, the solution posted there seems more intuitive, so I am linking it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32404/how-to-convert-this-sentence-into-a-first-order-logic-well-formed-formula) for reference of other users.